# Reversing role of group and set in definition of stabilizer

Tags: group-theory, definition, self-learning, group-actions

Given a group action of $G$ on $M$, we have the notion of the stabilizer of a point $m$ :

$Stab_G(m)=\{g \in G | g(m)=m \}$

, and we could extend this to a definition of the stabilizer of a generic subset of $M$.

Reversing the roles, we could do something similar. Given a subgroup $H < G$, we could define a subset in $M$ s.t. :

$U_H=\{ m \in M | h(m)=m, \forall h \in H\}$,

i.e. the set of all elements which is stabilized by all elements of the subgroup $H$.

If we define $U_g$ as :

$U_g=\{ m \in M | g(m)=m\}$

than:

$U_H=\cap_{h\in H}U_{h}$

Do these definitions make sense ? Do they have a proper "official" name ?

Comment: I have seen ${\rm Fix}_M(g)$ or alternatively $M^g$ used as notation for fixed point sets, and similarly for subsets of $G$.

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot ! If you want to put this into an answer I will accept it

Comment: Not only does it make sense, that kind of "reversal" is common in other areas. For instance, when working with rings and modules, given a ring $R$ and a module $M$, there are two "annihilators" you can define: $\mathrm{ann}_M(r) = \{m\in M\mid rm=0\}$, the elements of $M$ that annihilate the element $r\in R$; and $\mathrm{ann}_R(m)=\{r\in R\mid rm=0\}$, the elements of $R$ that annihilate $m\in M$. It is often fruitful to have both notions to play against each other.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Thanks for the comment :)